# Count values in column with unmerged cells corresponding to value in column with merged cells

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, rows of Column A is merged and the rows of Column B are not merged.

I want to write a macro for finding the count of rows of column B that are not blank for a corresponding value present in column A (which is merged).

[image]

Comment: What have you tried thus far? More than one would be willing to help you if you'd detail what's working/what's not.

Comment: I have tried this Macro but it did not work: =COUNTIF('Testing Scenarios'!D:D,"6-Feb",'Testing Scenarios'!H2:H223!=ISTEXT)

Comment: since the concept is same i just gave as column A & B for ease instead  mentioning what exactly the columns are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas...

```
'make sure to get the top-most merged cell
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("D3").MergeArea.Cells(1)
Set ma = rng.MergeArea

Debug.Print rng.Address(), ma.Address(), _
            rng.Offset(0, 4).Resize(ma.Rows.Count, 1).Address()

Debug.Print Application.CountA(rng.Offset(0, 4) _
           .Resize(ma.Rows.Count, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

To build a macro go to Developer > Record Macro and click <kbd>OK</kbd>. Press keys or buttons to suit and when the result is as desired click on Stop Recording.

Comment: i am not getting the desired output, could you please suggest me in how to write a macro to get the count for a value present in merged column of D,then the number of corresponding rows present in column H